# How can I write a unittest for this class?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-unittest

So I'm very new to writing unit tests and I need some guidance on how to write unit tests for the class I have written.
Any help will be appreciated
Thanks in advance! Also, I want to write the unit tests in pycharm.

```
class StringProcessor:
    def __init__(self, yo="", a="", b="", f=""):
        self.yo = yo
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.f = f

    def my_first_test(self):
        yo = input("Enter your string here")
        ya = yo.split()
        even = 0
        odd = 0
        for i in ya:
            if len(i) % 2 == 0:
                even = even + 1
            else:
                odd = odd + 1
        print("The number of odd words are ", odd)
        print("The number of even words are", even)

    def my_second_test(self, a, b):
            d = a.split()
            print("The word", b, "is repeated: ", d.count(b), "times")

    def my_third_test(self, f):
        d = {}
        lst = f.split()
        for c in lst:
            d[c] = lst.count(c)
        for key,value in d.items():
            print(key, ":", value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate the user inputs from the class to make it testable.

You do not need a class here, just a dict and a few fucntions.

Also, imho user inputs are evil, use `sys.argv` instead.